# Miller's test for pseudoprimes explanation for why we check $b^t \equiv 1 \pmod n$ and $b^{2^{j}t} \equiv -1 \pmod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primality-test

I was just wondering if there's an intuitive reason why for the Miller-Rabin primality test, we check whether $b^t \equiv 1 \pmod n$ oror $b^{2^{j}t} \equiv -1 \pmod n$ for some j with $0 \leq j \leq s-1$, where $s$ is a nonnegative integer, $t$ is an odd positive integer, and n is an integer.

Most links seem to just use as is, and doesn't mention why. I see how if we have $b^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ we can take it's square root, but I don't see why $b^t \equiv 1 \pmod n$ and $b^{2^{j}t} \equiv -1 \pmod n$ are the conditions for passing the test.

Comment: You might want to include some information as to how $t$ and $j$ and $s$ relate to $n$.

Comment: I don't keep the details of Miller–Rabin in my head, but surely, since $b^{2^jt}=(b^t)^{2^j}$, something seems amiss. I.e., if $b^t\equiv1$ then $b^{2^jt}\equiv1$ as well …?

Comment: Why can't $b^t \equiv -1 \pmod n$?

Comment: But you're testing whether $b^t\equiv 1$ and $b^{2^jt}\equiv-1$. I am saying this can't happen.

Comment: I'm not seeing why those are our conditions though

Comment: I am looking at my notes, and you should be checking whether one of the conditions hold, not whether both of them hold. I.e., replace “and” by “or”.

Comment: I fixed the question, thanks for noticing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the conditions do not hold, you get a nontrivial congruence x^2=1 (mod n), which immediately leads to a fatorization.

Comment: if x is not -1 or 1 (mod n), then gcd(x-1,n) and gcd(x+1,n) yield nontrivial factors.

Comment: I don't quite know what you mean here

Comment: First of all, b^(n-1)=1 (mod n) is necessary, that n can be prime.

Comment: Well n is a pseudoprime

Comment: So, there is a j , such that b^(2^j*t)=1 (mod n). If -1 never occurs, then b^(2^(j-1)*t)<>+/-1 unless b^t=1

Comment: You might take a look at [my lecture notes](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~hanche/notes/numtheory/). The Miller–Rabin test is described on p. 15. Note that Lemma 10 in those notes are pretty much what Peter is saying here.

Comment: My argument must be improved. It is necessary to choose the LEAST j>0 such that b^(2^j*t)=1 (mod n).